# Margin/layout fixes

Tags: css, wordpress

On my Wordpress site (http://www.peterchamberlaincann.co.uk) I'm using a child theme based on Minimalizine. There's some odd errors that occurred when I removed the sidebar and increased the page width from 520px to 720px, and also some things that differ from the Wordpress.com version of theme (that I was using before I migrated to my own hosting) that I'd like to change back.

- The text and images are stuck to the old 520px "margins" on the Portfolio page and also on the Blog, but only the images. It's also like that in WP dashboard when I'm editing a post.
- I want to put the sidebar back in, but only for the Blog and all . This is the code that will bring the sidebar back I think:

  ```
  .entry-meta {
      display: inline;
  }

  .wide {
  float: right;
  width: 520px;
  }
  ```

  .hentry {
      margin: 0 0 40px;
  }
- In the Leave a Reply box, I'd like to move the "Notify me" sentences so theyre alongside "Post Comment". I have already changed the respond code to these values:

  ```
  #respond label {
  left: 3.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  }
  ```

  which moved the "Notify me" sentences to right next to the checkboxes. It seems that label is too broad, because "left:" moves *all* of the text in that area, including "Name" "Email" and "Website".
- I think because of the change from 520px to 720px, the site now doesn't display correctly on my phone or tablets, or when viewed in a minimised window, so I'd like to fix this.
- I added this code to change the line spacing between images on the Portfolio page.

  ```
  .entry-content.wide img { margin-bottom: 6px; }
  ```

  But it has resulted in most gaps between header text and images being too small. For example, on the "Berlin" post on my Blog, the gap is smaller than the gap between "New film – Ever Decreasing Circles" and the YouTube video below.

  Oddly though, the gap between "Evaluating Ever Decreasing Circles" and the image below appears to have the correct spacing - I wonder if this is something that only affects tiled galleries?

  Even though the code was meant for the Portfolio page, where all the images *aren't* in galleries!!

Comment: Just providing CSS wouldn't make us to help you. Be specific with some more HTML code so that we can judge on which element the styles are applying.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to put the website address in, I'll edit it in now. I'm not really au fait with the way css affects html so I'm not sure which html would be useful.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation of problem. But the way is wrong. Explain point-wise the expected and what is presently causing problem.

Comment: I just started to edit it to be like that… but it seems unnecessary, I don't know the cause for most of the problems! The reason most of this has happened is because I moved from a Wordpress.com site to self-hosted .org, and made a few changes to the width of the content area.